# What is the best way to insert a snippet of code in spacemacs

Tags: elisp, spacemacs

I have a function which basically inserts `function () {};` but properly indented and the cursor positioned appropriately:

```
(defun insert-function-js ()
  (insert "function () {
};"))

(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "SPC dg")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (call-interactively 'evil-insert)
    (insert-function-js)
    (evil-force-normal-state)
    (call-interactively 'evil-visual-char)
    (call-interactively 'evil-previous-line)
    (call-interactively 'indent-region)
    (call-interactively 'evil-open-below)))
```

This seems very cumbersome. I would guess there is a better way to write this functionality! One that  better leverages elisp's capabilities.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You might want to check out `yasnippet` for inserting these kinds of templates: http://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/

Comment: I am currently looking into yas. It is a nice discovery, I'll definitely toy with it. 
I haven't yet found a way to execute a vim macro, except the key binding. Maybe there is a way to bind a yas snippet to a vim expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an answer to your first question, you could use `yasnippet` and a snippet based on the `function`-snippet provided with Spacemacs [1] to do this for you:

```
# -*- mode: snippet; require-final-newline: nil -*-
# name: my-function
# key: fn 
# --
function () {
         $0
};
```

If you put this snippet in a new file in `~/.emacs.d/private/snippets/`, you can expand it by typing `fn` and then pressing <kbd>M-/</kbd> [2]. If `yas-indent-line` is set to `'auto` (which it is by default in Spacemacs), then the function should be indented correctly, and the `$0` in the snippet puts your cursor in that position after insertion.

The `yasnippet`-expansion forms a single undo-action.

---

[1] The default `function`-snippet can be found in `~/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-<VERSION>/snippets/js-mode`

[2] using the default Spacemacs bindings, this calls `hippie-expand`, which in turn calls `yas-expand`.

Comment: From your comments, I've already defined a couple yas snippet like this one! It's working pretty well indeed. It definitely answers the first question. I will edit the question to extract the second one as a separate thread and mark this one as answered!